# How to extract Product from list of product for specific product id?

Tags: dart

please help me!

```
    List<String> Id= ["MES9-7t73JhFzAEoL6J","MES91YJevIAthak253M"];

    List<Product> products =
          [
            Product(
              id: 'MES9-2',
              categories: 'AC1, AC2, AC3, N1, Pn1, P',
              title: 'Red Shirt',
              description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
              price: 29.99,
              imageUrl:
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-tshirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
              ),
           Product(
             categories:' pn2, N2, N3, Pn2, Pn3',
             id: 'MES91YJevIAthak253M',
             title: 'Trousers',
             description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
             price: 59.99,
             imageUrl:
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
             ),
           ];
```

=> How to extract product from list of _items where  product id is same as String in Id List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final product = products.firstWhere((p) => Id.contains(p.id));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run two for loops to extract list of products corresponding to list of products ids you have. First loop will run according to the length of ids you have got and second according to the length of products. It will match both ids in the if condition and add the matching products to `foundProducts` list.

```
findProducts(){
    List<Product> foundProducts = [];
    for(int i=0; i<listOfIds.length;++i){
      for(int j=0;  j<productList.length; ++j){
        if(listOfIds[i] == productList[j].id){
          foundProducts.add(productList[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to iterate over your list, and find the match and return it. You can do via [firsWhere()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/firstWhere.html).

So, you will have to iterate over your `Id` using [list iterate dart](https://www.tutorialkart.com/dart/dart-list-iterate-over-elements/)

```
//you have the List<Product> we are taking the variable as products
List<Product> products = ....

// this will store the item which matches the id
var item;
Id.forEach((id){
  //now using first where
  products.firstWhere((item) => item.id == id, orElse: () => null);
});

// now printing the item and check for the nullability
print(item ?? 'No products found'); // You will get the matching the Product matching the item id
```

**Please note:** `firstWhere()`, gives out the first item found in the list matching the any of the ids. So you will single product only. I am assuming for the single requirement only.

I have a demo for you. Here you can make out how this works

**DEMO**

```
class Product {
  double price;
  String id, categories, title, description, imageUrl;
  
  Product({
    this.id, 
    this.categories, 
    this.title, 
    this.description, 
    this.price, 
    this.imageUrl
  });
}

void main() {
  var result;
  List<String> id = ["MES9-7t73JhFzAEoL6J","MES91YJevIAthak253M"];
  List<Product> products = [
    Product(
      id: 'MES9-2',
      categories: 'AC1, AC2, AC3, N1, Pn1, P',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      categories:' pn2, N2, N3, Pn2, Pn3',
      id: 'MES91YJevIAthak253M',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    )
  ];
  
  // Here is what we're doing the main operation
  id.forEach((id){
    result = products.firstWhere((item) => item.id == id, orElse: () => null);
  });
  
  //printing the result
  print(result ?? "No items found");
  // similary you can get the result item via result.id
  print("RESULT: ${result.id}, ${result.categories}, ${result.title}");
}
```

**Output**

```
Instance of 'Product' // so this is the instance of the product
RESULT: MES91YJevIAthak253M,  pn2, N2, N3, Pn2, Pn3, Trousers
```